# Simple Probability Question

Tags: probability

Question: The probability that a door is locked is 1/2. The key to the door is one of 12 keys in a cabinet. If a person selects two (2) keys at random from the cabinet, what is the probability that they can open the door without returning for another key?

My understanding is that it is (1/2) + ((1/2) * (2/12)) = 7/12

However I am uncertain as the selection of two keys confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The probability that among two selected keys one is the key to the door is given by
$$
\frac{11}{{12\choose 2}}=\frac2{12}
$$
since the order is not important. By the law of total probability,
$$
P(\text{open the door})=P(\text{open the door}\mid\text{locked})P(\text{locked})+P(\text{open the door}\mid\text{unlocked})P(\text{unlocked}).
$$
Hence,
$$
P(\text{open the door})=\frac2{12}\cdot\frac12+1\cdot\frac12=\frac7{12}\approx0.58.
$$